# Show and loader after click button on Bootstrap modal form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

I try to find solution for my problem during almost all day and finally I gave up.
I have aspx page with gridview. Click on any row opens standard bootstrap modal form with details. And on this modal form I have another gridview(lets call them Gridview2). Because adding new row do Gridview2 take few seconds (max 10) I want to run some loader. But bootstrap modal not allow to open more than one modal at the same time. I try a lot of jquery loaders but nwith no luck. Is there any solution to display loader over bootstrap modal form?

BR
Thomas

Comment: how do you bind your gridview? no postback?

Comment: This can be accomplished pretty simply with jQuery...On the event that adds a row, hide the table and show a loading image/text, and on complete, hide the loader and show the table. If you post your code, or better yet a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new), we can better assist you.

Comment: `$('element').click(function(ev){ev.preventDefault(); $('#gridview2).hide().parent().append('div class="loader"/>');});$callMeWhenDone = function(){ $('.loader').remove();$('#gridview2').show();};`